# ASP.NET Entity Framework Filter results by current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, authorization, entity-framework-6

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 and am creating simple CRUD pages using the Enitity Framework 6

I have also implemented the social login so I am logged in via google plus

My problem is that I want to filter the results of a table to only show the results of the logged user.  I can identify the logged user by calling this in the controller ViewBag.CurrentTestUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); and I can call this on my view page but I am struggling to filter the dataset below to show only the data for the logged in user

```
// GET: /Test/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var tests = db.Tests.Include(t => t.AspNetUser);
        return View(tests.ToList());
```

Comment: Did you try .Where()?

Answer (score 0):

you can apply the where clause filter on the linq query to tests. use the right column names for AspNetUser table etc.

```
// GET: /Test/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var tests = db.Tests.Where(t=>t.AspNetUser.UserId == userId);
    return View(tests.ToList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answer.

```
// GET: /Test/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var tests = db.Tests.Where(t=>t.TestUser == userId);
    return View(tests.ToList());
}
```

This works perfectly where Testuser is the column in my model that contains the id of the Asp logged user

Regards

Comment: Ehh, this almost repeats raja's answer. Of course he couldn't know about `t.TestUser`. I think you should mark his answer as accepted.